# pstree with Terminal problem

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I have a problem with ubuntu 13.10 terminal (release version, not beta), for example, I created a C program that creates child processes in a mesh, the problem is that when I create a sequence of 3 or more sequency children and run the pstree command to show the tree mesh of processes, is not fit or something, cuts it with a "+" as there are more but do not fit.

3x3 mesh example:

It should show the following (in ubuntu 12.04 shows this):

> roberto@rcanovas:-$ pstree -p | grep mash
>
> -gnome-terminal(2085)-+-bash(2116)---mash(2481)-+-mash(2482)---mash(2484)---mash(2487)
>                                                                                                                |-mash(2483)---mash(2486)---mash(2489)
>                                                                                                                `-mash(2485)---mash(2488)---mash(2490)

However, it shows the following:

> roberto@rcanovas:-$ pstree -p | grep mash
>
> -gnome-terminal(2085)-+-bash(2116)---mash5x5(2481)-+-mash(2482)---mash(2484)-**+**
>                                                                                                                        |-mash(2483)---mash(2486)-**+**
>                                                                                                                        `-mash(2485)---mash(2487)-**+**

I tried with konsole and xterm and same result.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `-l` or `--long` option

```
-l     Display long lines. By default, lines are truncated to the  dis‐
       play  width or 132 if output is sent to a non-tty or if the dis‐
       play width is unknown.
```

See `man pstree`

Comment: Thank you very much. I could swear I looked twice pstree help and had not seen the long parameter...